# NULL Characters in Firebird VARCHAR

Tags: sql, database, null, firebird, varchar

Im trying to find records in a VARCHAR column that may contain a NUL (0x00), and I cannot find a way to locate the NUL character.

Any ideas are welcome.

-Israel

Comment: select * from Pupils where PhoneNumber is not null

Comment: http://cse-mjmcl.cse.bris.ac.uk/blog/2007/02/14/1171465494443.html

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I ended up doing a trial and error approach to track down the VARCHAR column with the NULL character.  It doesnt seem possible to search for a specific binary character with SQL on Firebird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebird comes with an external function library (UDF library) that has an ASCII_CHAR function. You have to declare it in your database like this:

```
DECLARE EXTERNAL FUNCTION ascii_char
INTEGER
RETURNS CSTRING(1) FREE_IT
ENTRY_POINT 'IB_UDF_ascii_char' MODULE_NAME 'ib_udf'; */
```

Then, you could try querying:

```
select * from yourtable where column like '%' || ASCII_CHAR(0) || '%'
```

or something similar...

I must admit I haven't tried it, but you could and let us know the results :)

Comment: This worked beautifully.  Thanks I didnt know that UDF function was available.